# keep getting [Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined ] error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The problem have bugged me for couple of days and I still can't managed to solve it.

in my **main jsp** file [ **the tab or button**]

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
                            <li><a id="stream" href="" data-toggle="tab">Stream</a></li>
                            <li><a id="me" href="" data-toggle="tab">Me</a></li>                    
                            <li><a id="findout" href="" data-toggle="tab">Find Out</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
```

in my **main jsp file** [ **the div to display another jsp** ]

```
<div class="tab-content">
            <div id="suggestion"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="function_stream"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="function_me"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="function_findout"></div>
        </div>
```

and some javascript

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/find_out.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/me.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stream.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/suggestion.js"></script>
```

in my **find_out.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#function_findout').hide();
    $('#findout').click(function(){
    $('#suggestion').hide();
    $('#function_stream').hide();
    $('#function_me').hide();
    $('#function_findout').show();
    $('#function_findout').load('findout.jsp');


});

});

// and some google map code here( it work perfectly fine in normal (html + js) but not now
```

since I do load `jsp` page from another page, i believe there's the problem

The error log keep showing the error in this particular line which is

> `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);`

last but not least my **findout.jsp** file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCWDPCiH080dNCTYC-uprmLOn2mt2BMSUk&sensor=true"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>

<div class="map">
         <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the google api script file in the include section

Comment: sorry i just edited the findout.jsp part , i forgot to enter

Comment: I think you're trying to run `google.maps.event.addDomListener` before  including the Google API. The inclusion order matters.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have tried several time in different order but i still got the same error

Comment: guys is there any other solution ?